# How can I execute multiple commands in new batch (start)

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I wanna ask you how to execute multiple commands in start, but, I know how to, but I cannot set a variable for example:

```
start cmd.exe /k "set ram=1024 & java -Xmx%ram%M"
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: `set "variable=b" & call echo %variable%` also, if you really require the need of start, use window title quotes. `start "" cmd.exe /k "set variable=b" & call echo %variable%`

Comment: So... But what if I want use java command after that variable? Your way is awesome, but the second command (java -Xmx) is being executed in the actual batch, not in new

Comment: ok, then you need to be clear on your question. Edit you question and show what you really want to do using actual command examples and what is your end result supposed to be.

Comment: I'd use `start cmd.exe /V /K "set variable=b & echo !variable!"`; take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, your suggestion only works if `variable` is not defined initially; `... & call echo %^variable%` even works when it is...

Comment: Yeah, works as your example.. But Java still does not work with it, the command wich im using is a command that launchs minecraft client, so...

Comment: is this in a batch file? why do you want to do it in one line? I need to understand the reason for running a single start?

Comment: So adding `/V` and using `!ram!` does not work? The system's `%PATH%` variable contains the path to `java.exe`, right? By the way, also insert `""` in between `start` and `cmd` to provide a windoe title to `start`; otherwise your quoted command might be interpreted as such, unexpectedly...

Comment: Yeah, Im trying to make a launcher, wich will run the game, but then the launcher will be console, that should be fine, but it does not accept chars insert, so Im trying to do it in second "instance" wich will be "log", sorry for my english

Comment: Have you tried adding the full path to `java.exe` and `set "ram=1024"`?

Comment: !ram! works, but java says that it is empty so... It is not directly ram, it is !instancename!, but I think, it is no diffrence there.

Comment: Java does work. But Im keeping all the code in if %input%==start ( ..here is the cmd.. ), but if im doing that steps in cmd.exe, then it works

Comment: @aschipfl. Yes, but that was assuming no variable was set, also so will this echo a predefined variable. `... & echo %variable%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to run it in a batch file, see below, also as for your if statement comment, enclose in "" to ensure you do not catch unwanted whitespace
:

```
@echo off
if "%input%"=="start" set "ram=1024" & goto java
Goto :eof
:java
start "" java -Xmx%ram%M"
```